# Int to string conversion with leading 0s

Tags: c#, string, int, zero-pad

I currently convert an integer to a string for display to the screen, but wish to maintain 4 digits - i.e 10 = "0010". What is the best way of going from an integer of 10 to a string of "0010"?

This is in C# and .NET 4.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int num = 1;
// pad with 0 up to 4 places
string str = num.ToString("D4");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var str = 10.ToString("0000");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try :-

```
 string str = num.ToString("D8"); //padding with 8 zero's
```

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)